# how to move or delete dll file from system32 or SysWOW64 location in c# programatically

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll

I am trying to move one dll file programatically in c# from System32 or SysWOW64 directory. I am using following code:

```
string path32 = "c:/windows/System32/";
string path64 = "c:/windows/SysWOW64/";
string fileName = "mydll.dll";
string[] paths = { path32, path64 };
foreach (string p in paths)
{
    if (int.Parse(year) == 1)
    {
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(p);
        FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles(fileName);
        foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
        {
            // Do the renaming here
            File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(f.DirectoryName, "1" + f.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this method on certain condition in WCF service. When I do it my local environment, it is working fine. But when I am running on different machine, it is throwing following error:

> the server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the
>   service help page for constructing valid requests to the service. The
>   exception message is 'Access to the path is denied.'. See server logs
>   for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String
>   destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
>   at SyncInvokeCalculateFestivaldate(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

How can I give permission to get access in c# so that it will rename and move the dll file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator

Comment: Does the user the process is running as on the 2nd machine have permissions for the directory and files?

Comment: @MORCHARD I guess, it is not. Then how to take permission programatically.?

Comment: Negative vote commentor, may I know why this is getting negative vote. I know there are some similar questions but it is different than the other one, and I was not able to resolve the issue den only asked here.

Comment: System32/SysWow64 are not part of *your* file system - they're the systems. There shouldn't be anything that *your* application wants to delete in there because it shouldn't have put anything in there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To change stuff in the desired folders you need elevated (admin) windows privileges i.e. your app has to be run as an Administrator - which is a big security no-no. You are probably local admin and as such have rights to Change your own system that's why it works on your local Environment.